# Absolute positioned elements to look the same in Opera, FF and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a small template that displays a textarea and a close block.

I used Chrome to develop, but it looks different in other browsers.
**That close button changes its location in FF and Opera.**

```
<div class="video-box">
    <textarea id="id_video" rows="10" cols="40" name="video" placeholder="Embed your video here." class="has-     placeholder" style="display: inline-block;"></textarea>
    <div class="close" style="display: block;">close</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video-box {
    position: absolute;
margin-top: 25px;
}

textarea {
    width: 256px;
    border: 1px solid #C7C6C6;
    height: 100px;
    resize: none;
}
.close {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    top: 94px;
    left: 222px;
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

**What can cause this problem?**

http://jsfiddle.net/3hTH2/

Comment: Give maybe some screenshots of the differences. If it's minor differences, consider this approach: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: Change position of video-box class to relative, then you can position .close with absolute and it should be the same location in all browsers

Comment: @Feanor, did any of our responses answer your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to change.

First of all set font-size: 0; on .video-box, because it is inline-block extra whitespace can be added after the element:

```
.video-box {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Next, set margin: 0; on text-area to reset the default margin added to the element by browsers:

```
textarea {
    width: 256px;
    border: 1px solid #C7C6C6;
    height: 100px;
    resize: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Finally, use bottom: 0; and right: 0; instead of top and left on .close as it will ensure the button is positioned at the bottom right of the container no matter what size it is:

```
.close {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FVP6T/

Comment: You were close but your solution doesn't show/place the .close button correctly. Check my solution.

Comment: In what way is the button not shown correctly? I've checked the fiddle in Opera, FF, Chrome and IE and it looks ok and positioned in the same place.

Comment: Firefox (v30) is showing the `.close` button 1px lower than the outer box. Especially it looks ugly when using small font-size. It's strange, I know. Anyhow, +1 for the `font-size: 0 tip` :)

Comment: Strange, I'm using FF v30 and both of our fiddles look the same (minus the larger text on the button), tis a mystery!

Answer (score 0):

All those browsers have different HTML rendering engines, so some minor changes are inevitable. It's almost impossible to get everything looking exactly the same in every browser; I wouldn't even try.

Answer (score 0):

Try positioning from the right and bottom instead:

```
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 4px;
  /* etc. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hidden Hobbes's solution is/was the closest but it may still be treated incorrectly by Firefox - at least in my case, 'cause I see it is placing the .close button 1px lower.

So check this solution. At least another one :) I changed the font size on .close button to 30px just to see the difference better.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .close {
        margin-bottom: 1px !important; /* !important may be omitted */
    }
}

.video-box {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 0px;
}

textarea {
    width: 256px;
    border: 1px solid #C7C6C6;
    height: 100px;
    resize: none;
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.close:hover {
    background: grey;
}
```

Check the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3hTH2/6/)